# What are the .primary and .secondary colors in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the new SwiftUI, the type `Color` is very similar to `UIColor` from `UIKit`.

There are the common colors, as expected, but there is the addition of two other colors that I noticed:

- `.primary`
- `.secondary`

There is nothing in the Apple Documentation for the descriptions of the different [`Color`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color)s.

- **What are these colors?**
- **Which one should I use for certain things?**

Answer (score 74, accepted):

SwiftUI seems to be incomplete compared to what is provided by `UIColor`. The primary and secondary refers to the **text colors**, which are the `UIColor.label` and `UIColor.secondaryLabel`.

A simple extension to provide more `UIColor`:

```
public extension Color {
    static let lightText = Color(UIColor.lightText)
    static let darkText = Color(UIColor.darkText)

    static let label = Color(UIColor.label)
    static let secondaryLabel = Color(UIColor.secondaryLabel)
    static let tertiaryLabel = Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel)
    static let quaternaryLabel = Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel)

    static let systemBackground = Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
    static let secondarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)
    static let tertiarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemBackground)

    // There are more..
}
```

However, a huge drawback is that the colors will not automatically change between light & dark modes.

The above code is only for iOS, while macOS/AppKit does not have corresponding `lightText` etc.

Therefore, a better solution is to define such colors in [Assets Catalog](https://samwize.com/2022/06/29/asset-catalog-and-dark-mode/).

Comment: An important feature of UIColor.systemBackground is that it will adapt dynamically to light/dark mode. If we statically set systemBackground = Color(UIColor.systemBackground), will it respond to changes as UIColor.systemBackground does? Or would we require static var systemBackground: Color { Color(UIColor.systemBackground) } instead?

Comment: @Anton is right. Furthermore lightText and darkText are not dynamic although label is.

Comment: Actually colous do automatically change between light and dark modes, I tested it on my app. can you edit your answer please.

Answer (score 66):

#### Pre defined colors:

```
extension Color {
     
    // MARK: - Text Colors
    static let lightText = Color(UIColor.lightText)
    static let darkText = Color(UIColor.darkText)
    static let placeholderText = Color(UIColor.placeholderText)

    // MARK: - Label Colors
    static let label = Color(UIColor.label)
    static let secondaryLabel = Color(UIColor.secondaryLabel)
    static let tertiaryLabel = Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel)
    static let quaternaryLabel = Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel)

    // MARK: - Background Colors
    static let systemBackground = Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
    static let secondarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)
    static let tertiarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemBackground)
    
    // MARK: - Fill Colors
    static let systemFill = Color(UIColor.systemFill)
    static let secondarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill)
    static let tertiarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemFill)
    static let quaternarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.quaternarySystemFill)
    
    // MARK: - Grouped Background Colors
    static let systemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground)
    static let secondarySystemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
    static let tertiarySystemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemGroupedBackground)
    
    // MARK: - Gray Colors
    static let systemGray = Color(UIColor.systemGray)
    static let systemGray2 = Color(UIColor.systemGray2)
    static let systemGray3 = Color(UIColor.systemGray3)
    static let systemGray4 = Color(UIColor.systemGray4)
    static let systemGray5 = Color(UIColor.systemGray5)
    static let systemGray6 = Color(UIColor.systemGray6)
    
    // MARK: - Other Colors
    static let separator = Color(UIColor.separator)
    static let opaqueSeparator = Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator)
    static let link = Color(UIColor.link)
    
    // MARK: System Colors
    static let systemBlue = Color(UIColor.systemBlue)
    static let systemPurple = Color(UIColor.systemPurple)
    static let systemGreen = Color(UIColor.systemGreen)
    static let systemYellow = Color(UIColor.systemYellow)
    static let systemOrange = Color(UIColor.systemOrange)
    static let systemPink = Color(UIColor.systemPink)
    static let systemRed = Color(UIColor.systemRed)
    static let systemTeal = Color(UIColor.systemTeal)
    static let systemIndigo = Color(UIColor.systemIndigo)

}
```

#### Visual colors representation in light and dark modes:

[image]

#### Code used to generate color pallet:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Light")
                .frame(width: 75, height: 40)
            Text("Dark")
                .frame(width: 75, height: 40)
        }
        List(CC.colors, id: \.name) { color in
            HStack {
                Text(color.name)
                    .frame(width: 300, alignment: .trailing)
                Rectangle()
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(color.color)
                    .border(Color.black, width: 3)
                Rectangle()
                    .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 40)
                    .foregroundColor(color.color)
                    .border(Color.black, width: 3)

            }
        }
        //PlacesListView(places: placesViewModel.places, htmlAttributions: placesViewModel.htmlAttributions)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Places")
   // .embedInNavigationView()
}
```

And color list are taken from the **FarouK** answer.

```
struct CC {
    let name: String
    let color: Color

    static var colors: [CC] { [
        CC(name: "lightText", color: .lightText),
        CC(name: "darkText", color: .darkText),
        CC(name: "placeholderText", color: .placeholderText),
        CC(name: "label", color: .label),
        CC(name: "secondaryLabel", color: .secondaryLabel),
        CC(name: "tertiaryLabel", color: .tertiaryLabel),
        CC(name: "quaternaryLabel", color: .quaternaryLabel),
        CC(name: "systemBackground", color: .systemBackground),
        CC(name: "secondarySystemBackground", color: .secondarySystemBackground),
        CC(name: "tertiarySystemBackground", color: .tertiarySystemBackground),
        CC(name: "systemFill", color: .systemFill),
        CC(name: "secondarySystemFill", color: .secondarySystemFill),
        CC(name: "tertiarySystemFill", color: .tertiarySystemFill),
        CC(name: "quaternarySystemFill", color: .quaternarySystemFill),
        CC(name: "systemGroupedBackground", color: .systemGroupedBackground),
        CC(name: "secondarySystemGroupedBackground", color: .secondarySystemGroupedBackground),
        CC(name: "tertiarySystemGroupedBackground", color: .tertiarySystemGroupedBackground),
        CC(name: "systemGray", color: .systemGray),
        CC(name: "systemGray2", color: .systemGray2),
        CC(name: "systemGray3", color: .systemGray3),
        CC(name: "systemGray4", color: .systemGray4),
        CC(name: "systemGray5", color: .systemGray5),
        CC(name: "systemGray6", color: .systemGray6),
        CC(name: "separator", color: .separator),
        CC(name: "opaqueSeparator", color: .opaqueSeparator),
        CC(name: "link", color: .link),
        CC(name: "systemRed", color: .systemRed),
        CC(name: "systemBlue", color: .systemBlue),
        CC(name: "systemPink", color: .systemPink),
        CC(name: "systemTeal", color: .systemTeal),
        CC(name: "systemGreen", color: .systemGreen),
        CC(name: "systemIndigo", color: .systemIndigo),
        CC(name: "systemOrange", color: .systemOrange),
        CC(name: "systemPurple", color: .systemPurple),
        CC(name: "systemYellow", color: .systemYellow)]
    }
}

extension Color {
     
    // MARK: - Text Colors
    static let lightText = Color(UIColor.lightText)
    static let darkText = Color(UIColor.darkText)
    static let placeholderText = Color(UIColor.placeholderText)

    // MARK: - Label Colors
    static let label = Color(UIColor.label)
    static let secondaryLabel = Color(UIColor.secondaryLabel)
    static let tertiaryLabel = Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel)
    static let quaternaryLabel = Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel)

    // MARK: - Background Colors
    static let systemBackground = Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
    static let secondarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)
    static let tertiarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemBackground)
    
    // MARK: - Fill Colors
    static let systemFill = Color(UIColor.systemFill)
    static let secondarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill)
    static let tertiarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemFill)
    static let quaternarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.quaternarySystemFill)
    
    // MARK: - Grouped Background Colors
    static let systemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground)
    static let secondarySystemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
    static let tertiarySystemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemGroupedBackground)
    
    // MARK: - Gray Colors
    static let systemGray = Color(UIColor.systemGray)
    static let systemGray2 = Color(UIColor.systemGray2)
    static let systemGray3 = Color(UIColor.systemGray3)
    static let systemGray4 = Color(UIColor.systemGray4)
    static let systemGray5 = Color(UIColor.systemGray5)
    static let systemGray6 = Color(UIColor.systemGray6)
    
    // MARK: - Other Colors
    static let separator = Color(UIColor.separator)
    static let opaqueSeparator = Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator)
    static let link = Color(UIColor.link)
    
    // MARK: System Colors
    static let systemBlue = Color(UIColor.systemBlue)
    static let systemPurple = Color(UIColor.systemPurple)
    static let systemGreen = Color(UIColor.systemGreen)
    static let systemYellow = Color(UIColor.systemYellow)
    static let systemOrange = Color(UIColor.systemOrange)
    static let systemPink = Color(UIColor.systemPink)
    static let systemRed = Color(UIColor.systemRed)
    static let systemTeal = Color(UIColor.systemTeal)
    static let systemIndigo = Color(UIColor.systemIndigo)

}
```

Answer (score 23):

System colors are still missing from SwiftUI, and I didn't find the right way to use primary and secondary colors, until then you can use this extension to bring all UIColors to SwiftUI:

```
extension Color {
     
    // MARK: - Text Colors
    static let lightText = Color(UIColor.lightText)
    static let darkText = Color(UIColor.darkText)
    static let placeholderText = Color(UIColor.placeholderText)

    // MARK: - Label Colors
    static let label = Color(UIColor.label)
    static let secondaryLabel = Color(UIColor.secondaryLabel)
    static let tertiaryLabel = Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel)
    static let quaternaryLabel = Color(UIColor.quaternaryLabel)

    // MARK: - Background Colors
    static let systemBackground = Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
    static let secondarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground)
    static let tertiarySystemBackground = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemBackground)
    
    // MARK: - Fill Colors
    static let systemFill = Color(UIColor.systemFill)
    static let secondarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill)
    static let tertiarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemFill)
    static let quaternarySystemFill = Color(UIColor.quaternarySystemFill)
    
    // MARK: - Grouped Background Colors
    static let systemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground)
    static let secondarySystemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
    static let tertiarySystemGroupedBackground = Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemGroupedBackground)
    
    // MARK: - Gray Colors
    static let systemGray = Color(UIColor.systemGray)
    static let systemGray2 = Color(UIColor.systemGray2)
    static let systemGray3 = Color(UIColor.systemGray3)
    static let systemGray4 = Color(UIColor.systemGray4)
    static let systemGray5 = Color(UIColor.systemGray5)
    static let systemGray6 = Color(UIColor.systemGray6)
    
    // MARK: - Other Colors
    static let separator = Color(UIColor.separator)
    static let opaqueSeparator = Color(UIColor.opaqueSeparator)
    static let link = Color(UIColor.link)
    
    // MARK: System Colors
    static let systemBlue = Color(UIColor.systemBlue)
    static let systemPurple = Color(UIColor.systemPurple)
    static let systemGreen = Color(UIColor.systemGreen)
    static let systemYellow = Color(UIColor.systemYellow)
    static let systemOrange = Color(UIColor.systemOrange)
    static let systemPink = Color(UIColor.systemPink)
    static let systemRed = Color(UIColor.systemRed)
    static let systemTeal = Color(UIColor.systemTeal)
    static let systemIndigo = Color(UIColor.systemIndigo)

}
```

Answer (score 19):

Under *iOS and macOS Resources Updated* from June 3, 2019 one can find:

> Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, and Quaternary text style variants of all text styles

see here: https://developer.apple.com/design/whats-new/?id=06032019a

The Human Interface Guidelines section for *Dark Mode* reads:

> Use the system-provided label colors for labels. The primary, secondary, tertiary, and quaternary label colors adapt automatically to light and dark appearances. For related guidance, see Typography.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/dark-mode/

Finally the preliminary iOS 13 developer documentation reveals that these are predefined UIColors:

Primary:

> The color for text labels containing primary content.

Accordingly, secondaryLabel, tertiaryLabel, and quaternaryLabel are the colors for text labels that contain secondary or tertiary or quaternary content.

see here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173131-label

So these are UIColors that are intended for use with text labels. They are different colors, depending on whether they are important content (such as a heading: primary) or a description label (secondary), and so on. Finally, it automatically applies appropriate colors depending on whether you are using light mode, dark mode, or high contrast mode.

There is a WWDC 2019 video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/210/
which shows an example at around 31:40 from Apple Mail.

If you rewind a bit, the motivation is also explained very clearly and well with examples.

Comment: Are these `primary` and `secondary` etc colors set by `SwiftUI` for each item (such as `Text`)? Or are these universal colors, in different shades? I'm still a bit confused 

Comment: My understanding: These are normal UIColors that are intended for use with text labels. They are different colors, depending on whether they are important content (such as a heading: primary) or a description label (secondary), and so on. Finally, it automatically applies appropriate colors depending on whether you are using light mode, dark mode, or high contrast mode.

Comment: Yeah, could be. It would be great if you could investigate a little bit, to discover their true meaning (and of course add it to your answer). It would be a great help!  Also, which one shall I use in certain situations?

Comment: There is a WWDC video. There they explain the motivation and show an example from Apple Mail. I added that information to the answer.

Comment: Ah, so it's like it fades out from the theme. So for example, in light mode, `primary` is pure black, and it goes grayer.

Answer (score 4):

We can change `.primary` and `.secondary` colors by providing an Extension of `Color` like this:

```swift
extension Color {
    public static let primary = Color("SomeCustomColor") //Color that we have set in Assets catalog
    public static let secondary =  Color.green
}
```

Comment: Starting with Xcode 11.3 prevents preview compiling

Comment: I guess this is caused by the fact, that there already are Properties of Color called primary and secondary

Answer (score 0):

I have been exploring this as well. It seems that `.primary` is set to the "environment's accent color". So my best guess is that it's a system setting based on platform and may be affected by specific themes (like dark mode). Still not sure if you can change that on your own like Android themes. Using `.primary` in iOS 13 renders a light blue color.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/primary) on these details does seem to be pretty sparse at the moment.